# Kubernetes + Redis: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kubernetes, antiforgerytoken

I am making use of a Redis database for Data Protection on .net core 3.0 on Kubernetes, but still get the below error. Any ideas?

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
>         An exception was thrown while deserializing the token. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The
>   antiforgery token could not be decrypted.  --->
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key
>   {ffb146a1-0e5e-4f96-8566-425f7c2eb99a} was not found in the key ring. 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[]
>   protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus&
>   status)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[]
>   protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean&
>   requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[]
>   protectedData)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String
>   serializedToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String
>   serializedToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext
>   httpContext)

```
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REDIS_CONNSTR"));
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kubernetes, but in regular ASP.NET, if you have multiple servers in a farm, then each one must use the same machine key so that they can decrypt things that were encrypted by the others in the farm, so my guess is that it's something similar. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649308(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations

Comment: Thanks for the response, I fail to find references to machine key for .net core 3.0+, it seems to have been used with older versions of .net as per your article .net 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation in the below article the application name needs to be set.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys")
    .SetApplicationName("product");
```

> By default, the Data Protection system isolates apps from one another
>   based on their content root paths, even if they're sharing the same
>   physical key repository. This prevents the apps from understanding
>   each other's protected payloads.
>
> To share protected payloads among apps:
>
> - Configure SetApplicationName in each app with the same value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Just a further note on this. If you get a 400 Bad Request and are using an API in the same solution then I would suggest having a look at the IgnoreAntiforgeryToken Attribute to decorate methods where CSRF does not apply.

```
[HttpPost]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
```